# Using multiple packages versus a single package for the project

Tags: go, package

I have a basic go project structure as follows:

```
src/github.com/jeeves/my-project/
    |- main.go
    |- models/
        |- user.go
```

Contents of `main.go` are -

```
package main

var log = initializeLogger()

func main() {

    // do stuff

}

func initializeLogger() *logging.Logger {

    // build and return a logger

}
```

Contents of `models/user.go` are

```
package main

type User struct {
    Firstname  string    `json:"first_name"`
    Lastname   string    `json:"last_name"`
}

// other functions
```

I was curious about the best way to set up the package structure -

1. Should my `models/user.go` be part of `package models` instead of `package main`? What's the difference and how do I know when to use either?
2. If I do use `package models`, how can `models/user.go` access the global `log` object defined in the `main.go`? (As you can see, I'm trying to define a logger once and have it accessible throughout my app.)

Thanks!

Comment: This is a good discussion of package layout: https://medium.com/@benbjohnson/standard-package-layout-7cdbc8391fc1

Comment: 1. Yes, different directories are different packages. 2. You cannot share anything declared in the `main` package with any other package. Shared declarations should be in a non-main package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a separate package for your logging API,

Structuring your code into packages should be based on functionality,
Packages should be independent of each other and their names should represent what that package is meant to be.

If you have several `models` and `user` is one among them, and if many more `model` types are going to be added later, then make a package like `user`, `customer`, `...`, which are sub-packages of `model.

When import `user` do `.../modle/user`

Similar to `encoding/json`.

New packages can be added without many changes to the existing code with minimal set of changes.

Here is a the community maintained [github repository](https://github.com/golang-standards/project-layout) which contains project-layout information in more detail.